# Sqlite file at shared path for metro application

Tags: sqlite, xaml, microsoft-metro

Is it possible to share SQLite file path kept on shared drive such as Skydrive and get a copy of the same while the application begins? This way any updates to the data can be separated from the application functionality and no need to perform Metro app releases again and again for updation of Information within the app.

Answer (score 0):

I think its possible, but its a bad idea.

Consider this: what if two different applications change the same database at the same time? It's up to Skydrive to decide how to handle the merge and I'm pretty sure it does not know how to correctly merge SQLite files.

SQLite is meant to be used as an embedded SQL database. If you wish to share a database across several clients, consider using some full database solution, like MySQL or PostgreSQL. If you want to allow offline access to your application data, consider using a database like CouchDB that can gracefully handle multiple concurrent versions of your data.

Comment: There would be no update operations performed on this database. This database file would be only used for READ operation and hence i thought of not going with complete database solution. The logic would work in following way 1. Application starts and checks if there is update on skydrive. 2. If there is a update it would download the file and show information. 3. If there is no update, application would proceed with the version of file it already has.

Comment: Can you please suggest how my program can access a file from a common location from skydrive through multiple clients?